# Is there a native solution to pick files in NativeScript Angular?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to implement a feature to let the user upload a file in my NativeScript Angular Project. NativeScript does not seem to have a native implementation of a file picker and there are limited plugins available that can do the job. Plus they have their own set of problems. The closest I have come to a workable solution is using the [nativescript-mediafilepicker](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker) and that opens a blank page like the one below instead of the file explorer.

[image: Screenshot on Motorola One Power. Android Q]

I exactly followed the documentation and can't figure out why it's not working. Here is the service I wrote:

**payload.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Mediafilepicker, ImagePickerOptions, VideoPickerOptions, AudioPickerOptions, 
FilePickerOptions } from 'nativescript-mediafilepicker';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PayloadService {

  constructor() { }

  pickFile(){
    console.log('Pick File Payload Service requested');
    const extensions = ['pdf'];
    let options: FilePickerOptions = {
      android: {
        extensions: extensions,
        maxNumberFiles: 1
      },
      ios: {
        extensions: extensions,
        multipleSelection: false
      }
    };
    let mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker(); 
    mediafilepicker.openFilePicker(options);

    mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
      let results = res.object.get('results');
      console.dir('File Pick Success: ',results);
    });

    mediafilepicker.on("error", function (res) {
      let msg = res.object.get('msg');
      console.log('File Pick Error: ',msg);
    });

    mediafilepicker.on("cancel", function (res) {
      let msg = res.object.get('msg');
      console.log('File Pick Cancel: ',msg);
    });
   }
 }
```

Can someone help me fix this or rather provide me with a native implementation? I don't need much customization options and user will only upload one file at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by native solution, everything you use in NativeScript is almost native. It's just a JavaScript runtime, under the hood uses all native APIs. 1) Do you see permission dialog, did you accept external storage permission when you call file picker? 2) Did you try default pickers like image / video to see if it makes any difference? 3) Do you have PDF files in your device? If yes, which folder it resides exactly?

Comment: What I mean with native solution is a typescript code snippet that I can include in my service. For the questions you asked:
1) Yes 2) Used nativescript-simple-filepicker. It opens up file explorer but files are frozen i.e. there's a translucent white overlay over thumbnails and clicking those won't select the related file. 3) Yes. nativescript-simple-filepicker can show those.

Also, after posting this question I noticed that if I include 'jpg' in the extensions array, it shows a list of images on my device. It just won't detect 'pdf' and 'pdf' is the only file type I need.

Comment: Which version of Android you are testing it with?

Comment: Android Q on Motorola One Power

Comment: If you test the plugin in a lower version it works. This is due to the restrictions Android introduced in Q / v10. The long term solution is to migrate to scoped storage. Unfortunately there are no plugins which can handle it for you, you will have to achieve it by using native code.

Comment: And that is exactly what I am asking help with. I have no idea about writing native code. Can you point me to a source that might help?

Comment: The official android documentation is your source, if you haven't referred [marshalling docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/overview) yet, you might want to start there first.